# Type inference failed. the value of the type parameter t should be mentioned in input types

Tags: android, kotlin

I am beginner at kotlin and I am trying to filter items which are present in one list, however i am using a loop and iterator for this purpose. I am getting mentioned exception in the if condition `in` here . Can some one guide me where i am wrong.
I am pasting my function here .

```
fun getGateWays(
        gateways: ArrayList<JsonObject>?,
        callback: ResponseCallback<ArrayList<JsonObject>, String>
    ) {


        getDistinctGateways(object : ResponseCallback<List<String>?, String>() {

            override fun onFailure(failure: String) {
            }

            override fun onSuccess(response: List<String>?) {

                for(e in gateways!!.iterator()){
                    if(e.get("value") in response){
                        gateways.remove(e)
                    }
                }
                callback.onSuccess(gateways!!)
            }

        })

    }
```

Comment: could you attach the exception's stacktrace?

Comment: there is no exception its compile time error.

Answer (score 6):

You have to get a string value of each gateway in the list. You can do it with `asString` method of `JsonObject`:

```
if (e.get("value").asString in response!!) {
    gateways.remove(e)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because

```
    gateways.iterator() will give Iterator<JsonObject>
    e is of JsonObject type and response is the type List<String>
```